# Vue i18n pluralization with multiple parameters

Tags: vuejs3, internationalization

Hi I'm using i18n internationalization in my Vue app. It works for simple statements without any additional parameters but when I have additional parameters it doesn't seem to register them at all. For example, in my locale I have the following messages:

```
en: {
  message: {
    imageMessage: "1 image downloaded on {date} ({space} Mb) | {n} images downloaded on {date} ({space} Mb)"
  }
}
```

Here `date` and `space` are the additional parameters, not related to pluralization. In my vue template I have the following code:

```
$t('message.imageMessage', images.num, {date: images.date, space: images.space})
```

The messages that end up getting printed are either:
`1 image downloaded on  ( Mb)`
or of the form:
`5 images downloaded on  ( Mb)`

Is there a way to have these additional parameters printed in the messages as well?

I tried some other stopgap solutions that included conditional statements that were able to achieve this but was wondering if there was a way to achieve this without any additional logic.

Comment: Check [the docs](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/pluralization.html#accessing-the-number-via-the-pre-defined-argument), it should be `$tc`

Comment: I started off with this. `$tc` is not supported anymore. `$t` does the job now. However what I want is to be able to specify more parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem here is that the order of parameters for calling $t is changed.

Instead of:

```
$t('message.imageMessage', images.num, {date: images.date, space: images.space})
```

You need to pass them as:

```
$t('message.imageMessage', {date: images.date, space: images.space}, images.num)
```

Here you have the documentation for vue-i18n v9:
https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/composition#pluralization